# Are there interesting examples of medial non-commutative semigroups?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, semigroups, magma

There exist semigroups $S$ (written additively) such that

- $S$ is [medial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_magma), meaning $(a+b)+(a'+b') = (a+a')+(b+b')$.
- $S$ is not commutative.

*Example*. The left (and right) [zero semigroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_semigroup#Left_zero_semigroup) are all medial, but those having two or more elements are non-commutative.

**Soft question:** Does anyone know of other, more "interesting" examples of medial non-commutative semigroups?

A few remarks:

1. In an arbitrary semigroup, commutativity implies mediality.
2. In a magma with an identity element $0$, mediality implies
   commutativity. Indeed:

$$a+b = (0+a)+(b+0)=(0+b)+(a+0) =b+a.$$

Thus, every medial non-commutative semigroup lacks an identity element.

Comment: There appear to be a lot of them;  Maple says there are $2$ of order $2$, $10$ of order $3$, $94$ of order $4$, $945$ of order $5$ and $14136$ of order $6$ (up to isomorphism).  Surely, some of those are "interesting".

Comment: You might look at $\operatorname{Hom}( M, S )$, where $S$ is a semigroup of the sort you are interested in and $M$ is some magma.  It will automatically inherit associativity and mediality, and there might be interesting ways to ensure it is non-commutative if $S$ is.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the operation on $\operatorname{Hom}(M,S)$ is defined pointwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example: semigroups with the identity $xy=x$ (semigroups of left zeroes).

Another exemple: Let $A,B$ be arbitrary sets, $S=A\times B$ with the multiplication $(a_1,b_1)(a_2,b_2)=(a_1,b_2)$ (a rectangular band).

Moreover, there is a description of medial semigroups (similarly to commutative ones): Every medial semigroup is a semilattice of  medial archmedean semigroups. [A. Nagy, Special Classes of Semigroups. Springer, 2001; Theorem 9.3].